# Cannot find module 'mysql'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I went through the different proposed answers related to this problem while installing node.js mysql.

I tried about everything and I still get the same error message: "Cannot find module 'mysql'" either locally or on a webserver.

Checks I've performed:

1. Packages and dependencies are installed in myproject/node_modules
   ==> check
2. Run my database.js test script going into the folder and via the command line typing "node database.js" => this works
3. Tried to load in my HTML document the index.js file from node_modules/mysql
   before loading the file database.js => ReferenceError: exports is not defined. Also tried to put database.js in the main folder, same error.

I haven't trying copying my project folder in the c:/some-dir/nodejs because it is supposed to run on a webserver.

Any clue what's the issue here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share some code. Based on the error "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" that you have put I am assuming you are using ES6 module exports in your client js file. In the script tag add type as module. Eg: `<script src="path/to/jsFile" type="module">`

Comment: Where do you want to use the `mysql`? In the browser or using node.js?  **3.** indicates that you try to use it in the browser when you get the error message. But there is no possiblity to use the `mysql` module in the browser.

Comment: Royson: the database.js is basic example from W3School where I'm trying to connect to the DB and log "Connected" if success. t.niese, what I want to achieve is to use mysql in a callback function to upload my db once a web3 transaction is executed.

Comment: @ShamanLizardKing that does not answer my question. For **2.** you say it works, so I assume that it prints `Connected`. But **3.** is not clear, it seems as if you want to use the `mysql` module directly within the browser and not in node.js and this is not possible. `mysql` is a module that can only be used server side using node.js and not clientside in the brower. So do you actually try to use the `mysql` module directly in the browser?

Comment: It seems that I am indeed trying to use mysql in the browser. What I did is execute the script database.js in my <head> section of index.html. Is that not possible? Shall I use PHP instead for this type of operation? javascript would have been more convenient, because as explained I have to update my db once a callback is executed.

Comment: You can't do that in the browser. You have to do that server side. What languge you use server side does not matter. You can use javascript there or php, but you have to send the request to update the database from the browser to your server and there you update your database.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much!